# Using padding-box in combination with border-image adds unwanted thin-lines in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to use the CSS property `border-image` in order to add some custom transparent border designs to several links inside a sticky side bar. Thus in order to avoid painting over the transparent portions of the border image, I also have to set the `background-clip` property to the `padding-box` value.

Unfortunately this seems to be adding some thin-lines between the padding box and the border image.

You can check a simplified version here: https://jsfiddle.net/8ksot9z7/

And a follow-up version using a transparent dummyimage: https://jsfiddle.net/8ksot9z7/1/

Keep in mind that the dummyimage used inhere is just to exemplify the unwanted thin-lines that show up (otherwise this image would have a custom design with transparent portions).

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <a href="" title="1">1</a>
  <a href="" title="2">2</a>
  <a href="" title="3">3</a>
</div>
```

```css
.sidebar {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 1000;
}
.sidebar a {
    display: block; 
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;

    background-color: #ff0000;
    background-clip: padding-box;

    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 0 10px 0;
    border-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ff0000/ff0000.png') 50% 0 50% 0 stretch;
}
```

The vertical thin-lines only seem to show up in Chrome, while no lines are displayed in Firefox (see screenshot below). Also using this inside the `sidebar` class having the `top` and `transform` properties seems to trigger the bug.

[image: Chrome adds thin-lines when using padding-box]

Is this in the end a Chrome-related bug? What workaround would you recommend for this situation?

Comment: Where exactly is the line ? can you add a screenshot if possible ?

Comment: @XxSTREKxX if you open the linked jsfiddle in Chrome and FF you should be able to see where the lines are showing up; I also just added a screenshot to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was confirmed by the Chromium Project Members, this is an actual browser bug, unfortunately not likely to be fixed soon:

> Snapping issue we have had forever. Not likely to get action soon.

See bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1000600

---

As a possible workaround, it works to add a `before` pseudo-element having the size & color of the `padding-box` and a negative `z-index` so that it shows instead of the unwanted thin-lines, without covering the transparent `border-image`.

See jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/chrisdevht/pL0qr946/

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <a href="" title="1"><span>1<br>1</span></a>
  <a href="" title="2"><span>2</span></a>
  <a href="" title="3"><span>3</span></a>
</div>
```

```css
.sidebar a {
    /* everything else as before */
    position: relative;
}
.sidebar a span::before {
    content: '';
    background-color: #ff4c00;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to assess the complex example without the code but for the simplified example stated, you can change:

**From:** `background-clip: padding-box;`

**To:** `background-clip: border-box;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The code I included in my question (see also jsfiddle) seems enough to trigger the behavior I mentioned. Unfortunately your suggestion won't work in this case, because the `border-image` has transparent portions, thus changing the `background-clip` to `border-box` would make the `background-color` visible through these transparent portions.

Comment: I'm using Chrome and its working fine Chris. I tried it on the JS Fiddle. The issue probably isn't where you think it is but at the moment, it's not something that can be reproduced.

Comment: Is it really working fine when using the `padding-box`? Because I've tried it out on different computers with the latest version of Chrome `Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)` and the unwanted thin lines show up every time (just like in the screenshot I attached). It's also reproducible on other Chromium based browsers like Opera or Vivaldi. As I said before, it works fine / as expected when using Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `padding-box` to `border-box` works because the padding-box is deprecated and cannot be used.

```css
.sidebar {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 1000;
}

.sidebar a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 0 10px 0;
  border-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ff0000/ff0000.png') 50% 0 50% 0 stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <a href="" title="1">1</a>
  <a href="" title="2">2</a>
  <a href="" title="3">3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The `border-box` is not usable in this case because, as I mentioned in my question, the dummy image is actually partially transparent, and I don't want to paint with the `background-color` over those transparent portions. See here an updated jsfiddle using a transparent dummy image: https://jsfiddle.net/8ksot9z7/1/